# notation for sum of matrix columns

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Is there a name or notation for the vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, such that $\vec{v}$ is the sum of the $n$ columns of $A$?

Comment: $A \cdot \mathbf{1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, $\vec{1}_n$ denotes the $n$-entry column vector with every entry equal to $1.$ In that case, what you're looking for is $$\vec v=A\vec{1}_n.$$

Sometimes, $\mathbf{1}_{j\times k}$ denotes the $j$-row, $k$-column matrix with every entry equal to $1.$ In that case, what you're looking for is $$\vec v=A\mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}.$$

Sometimes, other notation is used. It's really context-dependent. You can frankly make your own notation, as long as it doesn't conflict with notation you've previously defined, and as long as you define it explicitly.